# Is it possible with SSRS 2008 to export a .pdf that has a dynamic name based on today's date?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I want to generate a report each day and then export that to a .pdf on a network drive.  However, I don't want to overwrite the current data.  Instead, I'd like something like this to happen each day:

ExportedReport_1242012.pdf for today

ExportedReport_1252012.pdf for tomorrow

etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You could set this report up as a subscription if @Timestamp in the filename is OK, or a data driven subscription if the date formats are critical.

See this thread for more info:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/81f47009-946a-4ebc-be43-7690236e829b

Answer (score 0):

Use @timestamp in the name of the report. For example `ExportedReport_@timestamp.pdf`