# How to rename dynamically an exported report in code or with reporting services itself?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have tried to Google my problem, but I have found nothing about my problem.

I would like to rename dynamically my reports from Reporting Services when I export them using the ReportViewer. Basically, the format will be `reportName + timestamp`.

Is there anyway to do that using C# or Reporting Services itself?

Here's how I include the reportviewer on my pages:

```xml
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rv" runat="server" ShowToolBar="true" ShowParameterPrompts="false"
    BackColor="#F0F8FF" Height="1200px" Width="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" EnableViewState="true"
    Visible="false" SizeToReportContent="True">
    <LocalReport EnableExternalImages="True">
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention @Jeroen.... The reports can already been exported by the basic feature of ReportViewer, and it can be a PDF, Word or Excel format. It also gets the name that I used to create the report. (Eg Sales.rdl will be exported like Sales.pdf)

Comment: Possibly [this question's a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8991673/419956)?

Comment: Thank you again @Jeroen, but data-driven seens to available only for the Enterprise Edition of SSRS... I will also need to change the report's name and the add the time stamp....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem using a simple method and I hope to be able to help someone with the code below:

```
    protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlExportFormat.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            ExportReport(ddlExportFormat.SelectedValue);
            btnShow_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void ExportReport(String format)
    {
        // Variables
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;

        string fileName = _reportName +"_"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm"); 


        // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
        ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
        viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(_reportServerUrl);
        viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = _reportPath;

        if (this.PrepareReportParameters())
        {
            viewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(lstReportParameters);
        }


        byte[] bytes = viewer.ServerReport.Render(format, null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);


        // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
        Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
    }
```

Credits to http://beta.codeproject.com/Questions/277989/How-to-export-rdlc-report-to-PDF-without-using-Rep

Answer (score 7):

@Devester - Thx so much for your post of the solution to your own problem.  It is appreciated and makes it easier for the rest of us!

So from your lead, I found that in my solution where I am using a local report (ie no Reporting Services), this was the only line I needed to add to change from the "MyReport.rdlc" normally exported to PDF as "MyReport.pdf" to something else:

```js
this.rptViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = _reportName +"_"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Just one line of Code
RptViewer.ServerReport.DisplayName = "Your File Name Goes Here";